# how to add two zeroes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm confused about how to add two digits in this function
I want the result to be as in the following example : `1.000.000,00`

my code :

```js
function FormatCurrency2(objNum) {
  if (objNum.value.substring(0, 1) == "0") {
    objNum.value = objNum.value.replace(/^0+/g, '');
  }

  var num = objNum.value;
  var ent, dec;
  if (num != '' && num != objNum.oldvalue) {
    num = HapusTitik(num);
    if (isNaN(num)) {

      // objNum.value = (objNum.oldvalue)?objNum.oldvalue:'';
    } else {
      var ev = (navigator.appName.indexOf('Netscape') != 1) ? Event : event;
      if (ev.keyCode == 190) {
        // alert(num.split('.')[1]);
        objNum.value = TambahTitik(num.split('.')[0]) + '.' + num.split('.')[1];
      } else {
        objNum.value = TambahTitik(num.split('.')[0]);
      }
      objNum.oldvalue = objNum.value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you would give some examples of expected input and output it will give you a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString), with the locale set to `de-DE` maybe, and the `minimumFractionDigits` option set to `2`:

```js
const num = 1000000;
const str = num.toLocaleString('de-DE', {minimumFractionDigits:2})
console.log(str);
```

And if you wish to fix it to two digits, then you'd have to also set the `maximumFractionDigits`:

```js
const num = 1000000 + Math.PI;
const str = num.toLocaleString('de-DE', {
  minimumFractionDigits:2,
  maximumFractionDigits:2
})
console.log(str);
```

Comment: I using keyup function but can't work.

function FormatCurrency3(num) {
   var digit = num.value;
     const str = digit.toLocaleString('de-DE', {minimumFractionDigits:2});
     console.log(str);
     return str;
  }

Comment: `HTMLInputElement.value` is always a string, the `toLocaleString` method I referred to is the `Number.prototype`'s one. You need to cast `digit` to a number e.g `digit = Number(num.value);` or if `num` is an input of `type` `"number"`, then you can use its `.valueAsNumber` property.

Comment: thanks.. now work. but the value form input can't change value as '1.000.000,00'.
I wan't to if type in form automatic change on form.

function FormatCurrency3(num) {
      const digit = Number(num.value);
         const str = digit.toLocaleString('de-DE', {minimumFractionDigits:2});
         return str;
  }

HTML

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Saldo Bank Bosnas" name="bosnas_saldo_bank" id="bosnas_saldo_bank1" onkeyup="FormatCurrency3(this);" autocomplete="off" required>

Comment: Well yes, `Number("1.000.000,00")` will return `NaN`. You'd have to parse it manually.

Comment: how to automatic type change on form? not change on console.log